# Recursive javascript function creating an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I keep on getting the following message:

```
angular.js:14525 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2) "<input date-picker="" type="text" ng-model="newclass.expiry" placeholder="Referral Code Expiry Date" onkeydown="return false" data-position="top left" data-timepicker="true" data-language="en" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope">"
```

I know that it means that somewhere in the code, I am calling a function which in turn makes infinite calls and so forth, until it hits the call stack limit.

I cannot seem to understand where it does that. Below is the the html element code.

The error comes when i add `ng-model="newclass.expiry"` to the input element.

If you have a solution on how I can stop getting that error, your solution would be appreciated.

I am using angular with an angular package: [ng-air-datePicker](https://github.com/think2011/ng-air-datepicker/)

```
<input date-picker type="text" 
        ng-model="newclass.expiry" 
        placeholder="Referral Code Expiry Date" 
        onkeydown="return false" 
        data-position="top left" 
        data-timepicker="true" 
        data-language='en' 
        required>
```

Comment: can you bring it down to the minimal amount of code that still ends up in an error?

Comment: @towc, i have considerably edited the question to reflect my scenario. The initial code was my attempt to find where the loop is happening.